# How to invoke diffrent jquery for a partial form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to invoke different jquerys for different methods in a partial form.

I need to hide a certain block if an "edit" method is called _form(partial form) but I need to make it visible for a "new" method.

Here is the jquery part,
 `$('.deact').hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking a `new` record you can use `@my_variable.new_record?` in the `jquery` using,

```
var is_new = '<%= @my_variable.new_record? %>'; 
if(is_new){
 $('.deact').show();
}
```